# Using Bootstrap Collapse Events in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience

I am using bootstrap collapse in my lightning component but I want plus and minus sign over the accordions. For that I read somewhere that we require bootstrap collapse events like hidden.bs.collapse or shown.bs.collapse. But I am not able to use that.

Link for your reference : [enter link description here](http://www.bootply.com/89084)

I tried to write the javascript code in init method of the component but with no success.

Could anyone please let me know where to put the javascript written in the above link.

Thanks!